# ansible playbook fails on one of the host

Tags: ansible

I am getting the following error int he ansible playbook. The machine xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is a debian 10 machine. Playbook is running via cron.But if I run the playbook manually it is succesfull

```
failed: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] (item={u'path': u'/home/sdf/.ssh', u'state': u'directory', u'mode': u'0700'}) => {"item": {"mode": "0700", "path": "/home/sdf/.ssh", "state": "directory"}, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

following is my playbook

```
---
- name: touch sdf known_hosts file
  file: path={{ item.path }} state={{ item.state }} mode={{ item.mode }} owner=sdf group=sdf
  with_items:
    - { path: '/home/sdf/.ssh', state: 'directory', mode: '0700' }
    - { path: '/home/sdf/.ssh/known_hosts', state: 'touch', mode: '0600' }
- name: add known_hosts for sdf user
  lineinfile: dest=/home/sdf/.ssh/known_hosts line="{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - x1
    - x2
    - x3
```

Answer (score 0):

When running it manually your environment is probably set up to have the proper ssh keys to access the remote. Using cron the ssh keys are probably not available.

Comment: the same playbook worked fine earlier. now it is not working

Comment: The most likely case for `Permission denied (publickey,password)` is that the ssh client (which ansible runs) doesn't have the proper ssh key to access the server. It needs to be checked why it doesn't find or use it. Either it tries to use the default ssh key (<cron user home>/.ssh/id_rsa), or something somewhere explicitly specifies another key. A (complicated) way to figure this out is to run ansible with `-vvvv` args, this would show/output the ssh command ansible executes. Then running the same ssh command with `-vvvv` would show the keys it is trying to use to access the remote.